# overriding Object methods good programming practice?

Tags: java, overriding

for a programming project we made about two dozen classes which we need. Is it good programming practice to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` functions from Object even though we are not using them? We think it might be good in case we need them in future, but we are not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you need a different implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` than those supplied by `Object`, don't override them. As described in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), the `Object` version...

> ...implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-`null` reference values `x` and `y`, this method returns `true` if and only if `x` and `y` refer to the same object (`x == y` has the value `true`).

You only override them if you need a different meaning for `equals` (as, say, `String` does). (And you are quite correct that if you override one, you almost always need to override the other.)

Answer (score 2):

Not really. Do it only when you need them.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point coding something that you know you won't need.

OTOH, equals and hashCode are very useful to override, and you might easily be using them without realising, e.g.

- Putting objects in a `HashMap`
- Testing for equality indirectly, e.g. with a unit test `assertEquals`
- Testing if an object is present in a collection

Basically, if you object has value semantics, is used as "data" in some way and is not a singleton then you will probably end up having to override equals for one or more of the above reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I would hesitate to override some methods simply because you "may" need them.  Let the need arise, then solve the issue.  Default implementations of these methods are provided and will work out of the box with collections, adding your own implementation may create issues.

Answer (score 1):

Some methods use `equals` even if you don't call it directly.

You should do it only if you **really** need it. (If `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashcode()` doesn't do what it needs to for your class)

Answer (score 1):

you should override `equals()` and `hashCode()` when you need to and you should ALWAYS override `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Do not override it unless you really need it. You really need to override these methods when you try to use these objects as a key for `HashMap`.